# Which piece of code is syntactically invalid?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I know you guys don't like HW questions here, but I really can't make sense of this question. It's asking me to look at this context free grammar and look at two pieces of code and decide which one violates the grammar. I've drawn parse trees for both and both seem to be be valid to me. Does anyone know why one of these would be invalid?

I've attached two pictures. The first is the CFG. The second is the two pieces. Any help at all would be appreciated. I may even be drawing my parse trees wrong.

[image: CFG]

[image: Code]

Comment: It might be helpful if you could include a description for your images, or even [include them inline](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (when you get enough rep - it turns out you need 10 rep before they'll work inline to avoid spam), so you don't get 'enter image description here'.

Comment: Look closely at the `<loop_statement>` rule.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is the first time I've posted images. I'll go edit them

Comment: @chris I'm looking closely at it. It says loop statement will become loop counter which contains the statement rule.

Comment: The statement rule can branch off to an assign statement, a loop statement, or an io statement. When doing a parse tree, it appears I can do all three here

Comment: I think I see it now. B would be syntactically invalid right? The loop statement rule says that the statement rule must be contained within the confines of the loop counter.

Comment: My apologies for keeping a huge string of comments going. No other way for me to ask some follow up questions. Thank you Chris for responding

Comment: The `<loop_statement>` rule says a loop can contain one `<statement>` (an `<assign_statement>`, an `<io_statement>`, or a nested `<loop_statement>`).  In other words, a `<loop_statement>` may not contain multiple statements unless it's a nested `<loop_statement>`.  Therefore, A is incorrect because it's `<loop_statement>` contains three `<statement>`s.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense to me.

Comment: However, I do have a follow up question. Why couldn't I use that statement to branch off to an assign statement and continue mapping out the rest of the code block?

Comment: That's the part that driving me a little crazy XD

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand what "use that statement to branch off to an assign statement" means. Could you give an example?

Comment: Since statement's rule says <statement> ->  <assign_statement> etc., couldn't I just use that statement to make a branch in my parse tree that goes to assignment statement. I'm thinking about this in terms of parse trees

Comment: @Gary - Because the `<statement>` definition doesn't support recursion.  See how `<statements>` includes itself?  `<statement>` does not.  If `<loop_statement>` used `<statements>` instead of `<statement>` then you could, but as currently defined, you cannot.

Comment: Please post only RELEVANT comments here. Not all of us want to read all of your thoughts.

Comment: I'll try to get better at that. My apologies. I'll be more patient.

Comment: Wish I could give you guys an upvote. Really appreciate it. I understand this stuff pretty well now